# How to custom tag word(s) in GATE JAPE grammar?

Tags: grammar, text-mining, gate

I have a set of documents and each document has different heading. Example if document heading says "Psychological Evaluation" I want to tag the document as "Medicalrule".

1. I loaded the document and loaded ANNIE with defaults.
2. In Processing Resources > New > Jape Transducer 
   2.1 wrote the following code in the text document and saved it as .JAPE extension

CODE :

---

```
Phase: ConjunctionIdentifier
Input: Token Split    
Rule: Medicalrule
(
({Token.string=="Psychological"})+({Token.string == " "})+ ({Token.string == "Evaluation"}):Meddoc({Token.kind=="word"})
)

--> 
:Meddoc
  {
    gate.AnnotationSet matchedAnns= (gate.AnnotationSet) bindings.get("Meddoc"); gate.FeatureMap newFeatures= Factory.newFeatureMap();newFeatures.put("rule","Medicalrule");annotations.add(matchedAnns.firstNode(),matchedAnns.lastNode(),"CC", newFeatures);
 }
```

---

1. Loaded the above created  .JAPE file and reinitialized

After the application is run the Annotation Set does not show the tag !

Am I doing wrong somewhere ?It would be great if someone could help me on this.

Appreciate your time.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues I can see here.

- First, as ashingel says, spaces are not represented as `Token` annotations - this is deliberate as in most cases you don't care about the spacing between words, only the words themselves.
- Second, the trailing `({Token.kind=="word"})` means that the rule will only match when "Psychological Evaluation" is followed by another word before the end of the current sentence (because you've got `Split` in the Input line).
- Third, you're only binding the `Meddoc` label to the "Evaluation" token, not to the whole match.

I would try and simplify the LHS of the rule:

```
Phase: ConjunctionIdentifier
Input: Token Split    
Rule: Medicalrule
(
  {Token.string=="Psychological"}
  {Token.string == "Evaluation"}
):meddoc
```

and for the RHS (a) you don't need to do the explicit `bindings.get` because you've used a labelled block so you already have the bound annots available, (b) you should use `outputAS` instead of `annotations`, and (c) you should generally avoid the `add` method that takes nodes, as it isn't safe if the input and output annotation sets are different.  If you're using a recent snapshot of GATE then the `gate.Utils` static methods can help you a lot here

```java
:meddoc {
    Utils.addAnn(outputAS, meddocAnnots,"CC",
                 Utils.featureMap("rule","Medicalrule"));
}
```

If you're using 7.1 or earlier then the `addAnn` method isn't available so it's slightly more convoluted:

```java
:meddoc {
  try {
    outputAS.add(Utils.start(meddocAnnots), Utils.end(meddocAnnots),"CC",
                 Utils.featureMap("rule","Medicalrule"));
  } catch(InvalidOffsetException e) { // can't happen, but won't compile without
    throw new JapeException(e);
  }
}
```

Finally, just to check, you did definitely add your new JAPE Transducer PR to the end of the pipeline?

Comment: Yes I did add JAPE Transducer PR to end of the Pipeline , Thank you Lan and Ashingel

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure that there is no annotation like: Token.string == " ". Try to use a SpaceToken annotation instead.
Also, why not to try gazetteers instead of hardcoding of texts values in to JAPE code?